# Define a DIV / SPAN ID used by Javascript and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to define a variable that is used by Javascript and DIV / SPAN IDs?

We have a code block written by someone else that we are using repeatedly on one webpage to monitor Minecraft server status, and for each of these we have been hand-customizing the code blocks. I'd like to just have variables at the top without having to wade in and edit the code directly each time. Currently:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.SF2W').parent().css("background-image",
...
    if (Status == "Online") {
        $('#SF2Wstatus').text("Online");
        $('#SF2Wstatus').css("color", "green");
        $('#SF2Wcount').text("Players: " + NumPlayers);
...
</script>
<div class="SF2W" id="serverdiv">
...
        <span id="SF2Wstatus" style="color:red">Offline</span> 
        <span id="SF2Wcount"></span>
...
</div>
```

The parts I am looking at above are "SF2W" "SF2WStatus" "SF2WCount"

Is there a way to put these in a variable above everything else, that is used by both Javascript and the HTML?

Pseudocode of what I'd like to do:

```
ServerName = "SF2W"
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.' + ServerName).parent().css("background-image",
...
    if (Status == "Online") {
        $('#' + ServerName + 'status').text("Online");
        $('#' + ServerName + 'status').css("color", "green");
        $('#' + ServerName + 'count').text("Players: " + NumPlayers);
...
</script>
<div class=ServerName id="serverdiv">
...
        <span id= ServerName + "status" style="color:red">Offline</span> 
        <span id= ServerName + "count"></span>
...
</div>
```

Since these IDs are being accessed within the global page HTML I am under the impression these IDs must be unique since they are being reused repeatedly for each server monitor.

Comment: Can't you just use functions?

Answer (score 0):

What you would do in the  part seems totally fine as you wrote it. Declare a variable called ServerName and that should be ready to go.

As for the  tags I am not able to see what context they are in. Maybe try to append them using jquery like so:

```
$("#parrentId").append("<span id='" + ServerName + "status' style='color:red'>Offline</span> 
    <span id='" ServerName + "count'></span>");
```

You can also try to use the $().html(); function if you dont want to just add it in at the bottom. Please tell me if you need more help :)